# INDEX MATCH using "configuration" strings in separate cells

Tags: excel, indexing, match

My attempt to use a value in a particular cell to configure the index argument has not been panning out well to this point.

I have attempted to create a configuration sheet to define the index ranges used throughout my working data sheet with a formula like this:

`INDEX(Config!R1C2,MATCH(RC1,Config!R1C3,0),Config!R1C4)`

In the `Config!R1C2` cell as an example I'd put something like `RawData!R1C1:R100000C100` for the index range, then in `Config!R1C3` I'd define the match lookup range with something like `RawData!R1C5:R100000C5`.

This is an attempt at allowing me to populate a report using Index Match, while avoiding having to reconfiguring every formula each time my raw data's format changes (which changes often and I have zero control over). With this configuration sheet I'd hopefully be able to just redefine the index range, and match range in one cell.

Comment: Two useful techniques for creating a dynamic named range are the `OFFSET-COUNT` approach and the `INDEX-COUNT` approach.  Both can be used to create dynamic ranges that adjust in row and/or column count based on the size of data.  With that range defined, you can do `INDEX-MATCH` or whatever else with the dynamic range.  `OFFSET`: http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html . `INDEX`: http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/02/25/excel-function-friday-index-for-dynamic-range/

Comment: If you want to use your existing approach and are typing references into those `Config!` cells, you will likely need to use `INDIRECT` to convert the string to a proper reference.  https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/INDIRECT-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your formula you would need to wrap the cell reference into an Indirect() function in order to evaluate the contents of cell Config!R1C2 as a range.

Indirect is volatile, though and may slow down your workbook.

Consider using named formulas (named ranges) instead. Create three range names (Formula ribbon > Name Manager > New ). Name the ranges and let them refer to the following

```
IndexRange = RawData!R1C1:R100000C100
RowRange = RawData!R1C5:R100000C5
ColumnRange = Config!R1C4
```

Then you can adjust your formula to this:

`INDEX(IndexRange,MATCH(RC1,RowRange,0),ColumnRange)`

You can always edit the named ranges, or you can use formulas instead of absolute references, which will make the ranges grow and shrink with the available data (avoids using thousands of empty rows and columns).

Comment: Thank you very much, these workbooks do tend to scale rapidly over the course of a couple weeks, your approach turns out to have led me onwards to the other awesomeness associated with dynamic named ranges. Very much appreciated!